# unable to retrieve data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

In this app I want that as I click on button the data from my database display on List View and by using OnItemClick() it should show another activity But Unfortunately my application is is being stopped as I click on Button Plzz tell me where m I getting wrong  Here is my activity class  `

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends Activity {
protected EditText searchText;
protected DatabaseHelper d;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
   protected ListView wordList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    d = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    d.addWord(new Contact("Apple", "Fruit"));
    d.addWord(new Contact("Ape", "Animal"));
    d.addWord(new Contact("Boy", "Male"));
    d.addWord(new Contact("Bat", "Playing Object"));

    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);
    wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            searchword(v);
        }
    });

}

public void searchword(View view) {

    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    cursor = d.getData(searchText);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.word_list, cursor,
            new String[] { "word" }, new int[] { R.id.word });
    wordList.setAdapter(adapter);

    wordList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    WordDetails.class);
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
            intent.putExtra("Word_ID",
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}}`
```

Here is DataBaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Word_Meanings";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Meanings";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_WORD = "word";
private static final String KEY_MEAN = "mean";

private Contact contact;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_WORD + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MEAN + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
void addWord(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_WORD, contact.getword()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_MEAN, contact.getmean()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateWord(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_WORD, contact.getword());
    values.put(KEY_MEAN, contact.getmean());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteWord(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public Cursor getData(EditText s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String sql = "SELECT id, word FROM Meanings WHERE word LIKE ?";


    String sqlArgs[] = new String[] { s.getText().toString() + "%" };


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, sqlArgs);


    return c;

}}
```

here is logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.NullPointerException 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.Dictionary.DatabaseHelper.getData(DatabaseHelper.java:107) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.Dictionary.DictionaryActivity.searchword(DictionaryActivity.java:56) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.Dictionary.DictionaryActivity$1.onClick(DictionaryActivity.java:47) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) E/AndroidRuntime(543): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "my application is is being stopped as I click on Button" If your app crashes, **always** post the LogCat errors in your question. Otherwise we just have to guess...

Comment: @Sam i have posted the LogCat

Comment: Great! The first two line of the logcat tell us that in at DatabaseHelper.getData() on line 107 you are trying to reference a method of a null variable. Please post your getData() from DatabaseHelper and mark whichever line is 107.

Comment: I guess you are missing this >> SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
in your getData() fn

Comment: @user1042031 by adding this, it started displaying data but it is showing repeated data and when I click on any of the item the application again being stopped showing the error: E/AndroidRuntime(564): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `Cursor` to populate an `Adapter`, the `Cursor` must contain a column called `_id` (note the preceding `_` character).

Either change your database `CREATE` to use `_id` instead of `id` or change the `SELECT` to alias `id` to `_id`. For example...

```
String sql = "SELECT id as _id, word FROM Meanings WHERE word LIKE ?";
```

NOTE: if you need to do things like `SELECT * ...` you won't be able to alias the `id` column obviously. In that case it is usually better to create the database table with an `_id` column.

EDIT: By the way, your `getCount()` method will fail as you are calling `cursor.close()` before attempting to use `return cursor.getCount()`. When you close a `Cursor`, its resources are released and the `Cursor` is invalidated meaning `cursor.getCount()` won't work.

EDIT: Also, as mentioned, use `SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase()` before calling `db.rawQuery(...)` in your `getData(...)` method.

Comment: thanx... now it is displaying the data but it is showing repeated data and when I click on any of the item the application again being stopped showing the error: E/AndroidRuntime(564): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.